How to customize WooCommerce product pages with Elementor?
I’m trying to customize a WooCommerce product page using Elementor, but I’ve run into some challenges and I’m hoping someone can help.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I created a product in WooCommerce.
I installed the "Extra Product Options" plugin to add color swatches and make the product image change based on the selected color.
The issue is that WooCommerce product pages seem to have limited customization options, so I wanted to use Elementor to edit the page design. However:
When I try to use Elementor to edit the product page, it doesn’t allow me to make any changes to the product or its layout.
If I switch the page layout to "Elementor Canvas," the product and all its variations (including the extra options) disappear.
I also tried looking for a shortcode to embed the product and its options on an Elementor page, but I couldn’t find anything that works.
Can anyone guide me on how to:
Turn my WooCommerce product page into an editable Elementor page.
Ensure that the product and the features from the "Extra Product Options" plugin still function correctly?
I’d really appreciate any advice or solutions. Thanks in advance!
Can anyone guide me on how to:
Turn my WooCommerce product page into an editable Elementor page.
Ensure that the product and the features from the "Extra Product Options" plugin still function correctly?
I’d really appreciate any advice or solutions. Thanks in advance!
